# Writing usable dates into MySQL from Google Sheet

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I have a script writing data from a google sheet into a Google Cloud MySQL table but want to have dates that are usable by Data Studio. I've tried using Date, Datetime, and Timestamps but I get the same error:

> Attempted to update TABLE `sampledata` in DB `TestData`, but the following error was returned: Exception: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)' for column 'dateordered' at row 1

I've tried using the `ToDate` function in Data Studio to change it into a date, but it still won't recognize it. I feel like i'm bashing my head against a wall, and wanted to get some fresh ideas on how to do this. This is the script that is running in GAS to write into the MySQL table.

```
function LessCo1() {

  var sheetName = 'Sheet';

  var dbAddress = 'Address';
  var dbUser = 'User';
  var dbPassword = 'Pass';
  var dbName = 'TestData';
  var dbTableName = 'sampledata';

  var dbURL = 'jdbc:mysql://' + dbAddress + '/' + dbName;

  var sql = "INSERT INTO " + dbTableName + " (name, productkey, businesspartner, dateordered, price, quantity, promisedate, deliverydate, deliveredqty, market, doctype, docstat, docno, orderref) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
  
  var maxRecordsPerBatch = 50;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  var sheetData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 10000, 14).getValues();

  var dbConnection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);

  var dbStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
  
  var name, productkey, businesspartner, dateordered, price, quantity, promisedate, deliverydate, deliveredqty, market, doctype, docstat, docno, orderref;

  var recordCounter = 0;
  var lastRow;

  dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 9000; i++) 
  {

    lastRow = (i + 1 == sheetData.length ? true : false);
    
    name = sheetData[i][0];
    productkey = sheetData[i][1];
    businesspartner = sheetData[i][2];
    dateordered = sheetData[i][3];
    price = sheetData[i][4];
    quantity = sheetData[i][5];
    promisedate = sheetData[i][6];
    deliverydate = sheetData[i][7];
    deliveredqty = sheetData[i][8];
    market = sheetData[i][9];
    doctype = sheetData[i][10];
    docstat = sheetData[i][11];
    docno = sheetData[i][12];
    orderref = sheetData[i][13];
    
    
    dbStatement.setString(1, name);
    dbStatement.setString(2, productkey);
    dbStatement.setString(3, businesspartner);
    dbStatement.setString(4,dateordered);
    dbStatement.setString(5, price);
    dbStatement.setString(6, quantity);
    dbStatement.setString(7, promisedate);
    dbStatement.setString(8, deliverydate);
    dbStatement.setString(9, deliveredqty);
    dbStatement.setString(10, market);
    dbStatement.setString(11, doctype);
    dbStatement.setString(12, docstat);
    dbStatement.setString(13, docno);
    dbStatement.setString(14, orderref);

    dbStatement.addBatch();

    recordCounter += 1;

    if (recordCounter == maxRecordsPerBatch || lastRow)
    {
      try {
        dbStatement.executeBatch();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        console.log('Attempted to update TABLE `' + dbTableName + '` in DB `' + dbName + '`, but the following error was returned: ' + e);
      }

      if (!lastRow)
      { 
        dbStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall( sql );
        recordCounter = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  dbConnection.commit();
  dbConnection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The date format you are passing to the table is incorrect. The error you are receiving tells you that the string **'Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)'** is not the `datetime` object it expects for `dateordered` column.

So, your date needs to be converted to a `DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` object. To get there you need to use string manipulation and remove unnecessary parts. For example:

```js
 var myDate = 'Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)'.split(" ").splice(0,6);
 var timeZone = myDate.slice(-1)[0].split("GMT");
 timeZone[0] = "GMT";
 console.log(timeZone);
 // ["GMT", "-0500"]
 myDate = myDate.slice(0,5).join(" ");
 console.log(myDate);
 // "Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00"
```

Now that you parted with the needless let's put that date into the SQL table shall we?

The following is an example with a table of one column of `datetime` type, and you should adapt it to your JS code in your `var sql`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
    dateordered datetime
);
INSERT INTO foo_bar (dateordered) VALUES (CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(myDate,"%a %b %d %Y %T"),timeZone[0],timeZone[1]));
SELECT * FROM foo_bar ;
// Output: "2018-12-31 20:00:00"
```

You now have a datetime object in your DB table that was converted to GMT timezone, so keep that in mind when reading from the db, in some cases you may want to use [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to localize it.

Use [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert dates from strings to SQL datetime.

**From the documentation:** "It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning."

Comment: In this case, where would I convert from a string into a proper date? would there be a way to convert it in the script instead of in MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for editing, when it comes down to it I need it to be able to do this for 3 columns (dateordered, promisedate, and deliverydate) is there a way to run this quickly within the function I have now? How would it look if I needed to convert those three entries into a DATE instead of DATETIME since all of them log 00:00:00?

Comment: Then drop the unnecessary parts from the string and use the correct format that the table expects. For the format see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format.